# How do you prove that this function is bijective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

How do you prove that this function is bijective?
$f\colon (0,1)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$
$f(x)=\tan (\pi(x-1/2))$
In fact I want to show that $(0,1)$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ by proving that $f$ is bijective. Using Derivative concept and the Intermediate value theorem, it's easy to prove that is bijective, but I'm not allowed to use them.

Comment: Well it follows from naive geometrical reasoning. Is that allowed?

Comment: You could use the geometric properties of $\operatorname{tan}$.

Comment: @RobArthan  I just allowed to prove it by definitions of 1-1 and onto function, but I'd like to see your solution, too.

Comment: What definitions of $\tan$ and $\pi$ are you using?

Comment: You need at least the Intermediate value theorem. To show it's monotonic on $(0,1)$, you don't need the derivative.

Comment: The naive geometric solution is to observe that as the hour hand of a clock goes from 12 round to 6, the aspect ratio of the rectangle with the hour hand as its diagonal goes from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ (given suitable conventions for the sign of the aspect ratio). If you need a more formal proof, then we need to know what definitions of $\tan$ and $\pi$ you are allowed to use?

Comment: @RobArthan: The definitions we use normally in calculus. In other words, not specific definitions.

Comment: Why not use $\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x}$ instead? It should be easy to write down the inverse function.

Comment: Your "normally in calculus" is not my "normally in calculus", but let me put that to one side and put it another way: you've told us some properties of $\tan$ and $\pi$ that you are not allowed to use. What properties are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

"Draw" the unit half-circle with $x > 0$ and the tangent line at $(1, 0)$. Any point on that line determines a unique line segment to the origin, which interects the half-circle in a unique point . Conversely, each point on the half-circle uniquely determines a ray from the origin, which intersects the line in a unique point. Thus there is a bijection between the half-circle and the line. There is are bijections between the line and the real numbers and between the half-circle and the interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$, both based on directed distance from the point $(1, 0)$ along the respective curves. The combination of these three bijections is the function $\tan$. Therefore it is a bijection. Composing it with one other easily-seen bijection gives the result you want.